# Calling external command in Mathematica

Tags: function, wolfram-mathematica, executable

I can normally use my "exe" when executing a command in Mathematica. However, when I try to do this inside a function, it does not seem to work. Does anyone know why?

1. In the main function:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZPF3l.png)

2. Inside a callable function:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4brdo.png)